# How can I send a user to another url without a header redirect?

Tags: php, redirect

I'm learning PHP and been looking for this for a while. What I want to achieve is something like so:

```
if (true/false) {
    go to this url;
}
```

Every time I search terms like php redirects or php links etc., 99% of the time I get something "headers". I read that header redirects can achieve this but no code can go before it, that it must be first on the page else it wont work.

If that's so, then how can I achieve this?

Comment: You can't have any output before doing a header redirect, but they are usually the way to go. Thinking about how you can do the true/false check before any HTML is output is usually a better idea than trying to find a way to redirect to a page in the middle of rendering

Comment: If you've outputted something already, you can use either JavaScript's `document.location="url";` or the deprecated meta refresh tag: https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Meta_refresh

Comment: thanks fellas. ill take your advice pekka and put it b4 anything renders ...im check certain values from a form against certain values on a db so thatd be the way to go. thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> i read that header redirects can achieve this but no code can go before it. that it must be first on the page else it wont work.

That's wrong. There must be no *output* before this. Thus you have to ensure, that you don't `echo`, `print`, `?>something<?php` (or whatever) anything before.

```
if (true)  {
  header('Location: ' . $url, false, 302);
  exit; // Ensures, that there is no code _after_ the redirect executed
}
```

You can ready everything [about it in the official manual](http://php.net/header). Especially:

> Remember that header() must be called before any actual output is sent, either by normal HTML tags, blank lines in a file, or from PHP. It is a very common error to read code with include(), or require(), functions, or another file access function, and have spaces or empty lines that are output before header() is called. The same problem exists when using a single PHP/HTML file.

Comment: And even if you think you may, you can use [output buffering](http://php.net/manual/en/book.outcontrol.php) if you're that worried.

Comment: ahh ok ok i see. i misunderstood the "output" part lmao. thanks for that!. and thank you too Brad.

Answer (score 5):

```
echo '<script type="text/javascript"> document.location = "http://yoururl.com";</script>'
```

and this will be executed when this part of script is executed.

Comment: I upvoted because you gave an answer that wasn't header (like he mentions in the question) but I don't know it I should have because I feel what he really needed was someone to explain the output buffer :P

Answer (score 0):

You *can* use this if you need some output before the redirect:

```
header("refresh: $time_in_seconds; url=$your_url);
```

You still must call this before output is actually sent however. Send the header, then send your output - the page will "redirect" in the time specified.

**Disclaimer:** I must admit, I'm not sure what the implications of this are and can't find docs on it, so I can't necessarily recommend it - but I can validate that it works.